# Embed HTML5 player in Facebook timeline

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I see youtube has lately got their HTML5 player in the FB timline.

I want to get my videojs player do the same. I know FB allows Flash players, but i do not want to go down that road.
HTML5 offers a lot of opportunities.

Comment: HTML5 is only available for some companies that are testing the feature. When it will be available for everyone it will be announced on developers.facebook.com

Comment: @WizKid - any idea when they would launch it?